# How move image between web-pages?

Tags: php, html, image, move

I am going to move image from `home.php` to `image.php` using php or javascript.

My code:

> in home.php

```
    <div class="img">
      <a href="image.php">
         <img src="www.domain.com/image.jpg">
      </a>
    </div>
```

> in image.php

```
    <div class="img">
      <img src="www.domain.com/image.jpg">
    </div>
```

Please someone help me?

Comment: What did you mean under "move image"?

Answer (score 0):

send image link in url in home.php

```
  <div class="img">
      <a href="image.php?imgurl=www.domain.com/image.jpg">
         <img src="www.domain.com/image.jpg">
      </a>
    </div>
```

and access this with `$_GET['imgurl']` in image.php

```
<div class="img">
  <img src="<?php echo $_GET['imgurl'] ?>">
</div>
```

Comment: how do i change the url (image.php?imgurl=www.domain.com/image.jpg) to (www.mydomain.com/image/image.jpg)

Comment: in image.php   $_GET['imgurl']  will give you (www.mydomain.com/image/image.jpg)  not (image.php?imgurl=www.domain.com/image.jpg)